# How to make update button disabled, When all mandatory filled are filled on click of edit using angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

in my application, i have save and update button.
 I am using reactive forms, if validators field is not filled then save button is disabled and enables once  all validator fields are filled.
But in case of update button, as all validator fields are filled it shows enable all time.
Now on click of edit i want update button to be disabled and if i edit any one of the field in edit mode then Update button must be enabled provided all validator field is filled.

HTML:

```
 <div class="col-sm-12 col-xs-12 emr-labels no-padd" [formGroup]="emrPatientdetailsForm">
          <div class="col-sm-12 no-padd">
            <div class="col-sm-4  pull-left m-b10 m-t10">
              <label class="col-sm-5 pull-left col-form-label g-color-gray-dark-v2 g-font-weight-700 text-sm-left no-padd">MiddleName</label>
              <div class="col-sm-7 pull-left no-padd" >
                <div class="input-group g-brd-primary--focus">
                  <input class="form-control form-control-md rounded-0 pr-0" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="MiddleName" formControlName="MiddleName">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4 pull-left m-b10 m-t10">
              <label class="col-sm-5 pull-left col-form-label g-color-gray-dark-v2 g-font-weight-700 text-sm-left no-padd">
                LastName
                <span class="required">*</span>
              </label>
              <div class="col-sm-7 pull-left no-padd" >
                <div class="input-group g-brd-primary--focus">
                  <input class="form-control form-control-md rounded-0 pr-0" type="text" maxlength="50" placeholder="LastName" formControlName="LastName">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-sm-12 text-right m-b10 inline-block">
            <button class="btn btn-primary clr-white m-b10" [disabled]="!emrPatientdetailsForm.valid" (click)="!patientId ? saveEmrPatient() : updateEmrPatient()">{{!patientId ? 'Save' : 'Update'}}</button>
          </div>
        </div>
```

TS:

```
 public patientFormInit() {
    //Add
    this.PatientForm = this.FB.group({
      MiddleName: null,
      LastName: [null, Validators.required],
    });
  }

  public updateEmrPatient() {
    let updateParams = this.PatientForm.value;
    this.emrService.updateEmrPatientBasicInfo(updateParams).subscribe(res => {
      this.successMessagePopup(res);
    })
  }
private getPateintBasicInfo() {
    let params = { 'Id': this.userId }
    this.emrService.PatientBasicInfo(params).subscribe(pateintBasicInfoLists => {
      this.listPatientInfo = pateintBasicInfoLists.Body.Data[0];
      this.patientId = pateintBasicInfoLists.Body.Data[0][0].Id;
      let res = pateintBasicInfoLists.Body.Data[0][0];
      this.PatientForm.patchValue({
        Id: res.Id,
        FirstName: res.FirstName,
        MiddleName: res.MiddleName,
        LastName: res.LastName,
      });
    })
  }
```

Comment: Where is the edit button or edit action?

Comment: <button class="btn btn-primary clr-white m-b10" [disabled]="!emrPatientdetailsForm.valid" (click)="!patientId ? saveEmrPatient() : updateEmrPatient()">{{!patientId ? 'Save' : 'Update'}}</button>

Comment: Could you add those `patientId` and `saveEmrPatient` values ?

Comment: sorry i have not added that patientID, i will update

Comment: this patient id comes from backend, when i save the data then save buttons converts into updaste

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use !form.touched to check whether form is been edited:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary clr-white m-b10" [disabled]="!emrPatientdetailsForm.valid && !emrPatientdetailsForm.touched" (click)="!patientId ? saveEmrPatient() : updateEmrPatient()">{{!patientId ? 'Save' : 'Update'}}</button>
```

Comment: Update the operand from && to ||. Also add dirty flag like [disabled]=(!form.valid || !form.touched || !form.dirty)

Comment: Yeah. If you use !form.dirty, no need to use !form.touched.

Answer (score 1):

Check the dirty flag of your form.

```
[disabled]="!emrPatientdetailsForm.valid || !emrPatientdetailsForm.dirty"
```

This will only return false and therefore enable the button if a form value was changed.

Comment: Sorry even this doest work, update button is enabled

Comment: The dirty flag should not return true after your component was initially rendered. Could you please post some more of your code?

Comment: ya sure i will. here i am using reactive forms as the validators are already filled i am unable to solve that

Comment: Yes, my bad. Boolean algebra and an impending cold do not mix well ;-)

Comment: Can u pls give idea for this as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53064446/how-to-close-the-p-calender-after-selecting-date-in-angular2