# How to close the p- calender after selecting date in angular2

Tags: angular, primeng

I have used prime ng calender, when i select the date, the calender is not closing
How do i close the calender  after selecting date.

HTML:

```
 <p-calendar [monthNavigator]="true" [yearNavigator]="true" yearRange="1910:2020" showButtonBar="true" showTime="true" dateFormat="mm-dd-yy"
              placeholder="mm-dd-yyyy" formControlName="End" [minDate]="yesterday" class="pull-left"></p-calendar>
```

For reference i am adding link

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjupfn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example from [primeng calendar demo](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/calendar) works in your example, just add:

```
<div><p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date1"></p-calendar></div>
```

or, in your example:

```
<div><p-calendar [(ngModel)]="date1" showTime="true" hideOnDateTimeSelect="true" ></p-calendar></div>
```

So, since `showTime` property is used, you need `hideOnDateTimeSelect="true"` for the behaviour you've described.

Answer (score 0):

Since it is popup, `inline` is not set to `true`, it must close when date is picked. I'd remove one by one attribute for test.
Check also the console in case some errors are logged.

---

update: you are missing some required modules for angular application. Console:

> Please include either "BrowserAnimationsModule" or "NoopAnimationsModule" in your application.

This is not related to p-calendar. p-calendar is not rendered.

---

update2: you have primeng v6 and angular v7. They don't match. I'd try it with angular v6 or if there is primeng v7 for angular v7.

Comment: At a first glance I don't see to what property is mapped p-calendar. AppComponent doesn't have "value" attribute.

Comment: Please, check if you have compatible angular and primeng versions as noted in update2.

Comment: It doesn't work with v6 neither: https://angular-at3dqf.stackblitz.io , but if showIcon is set to true calendar can be removed by click on the button. (toggle-on/off).

Comment: ya, so only can we add OnClose method or selecting of date manually can we close?

Answer (score -1):

I have the same problem with working prime ng controls version v7 angular 6

You can just add `hideOnDateTimeSelect="true"` in to your input code and 
automatically it will disappear after selection of date and time